# VB scripting in bartender label software

Tags: vbscript, bartender

Hi I am trying to code vb scripting for my bartender label,
Can any one help me how can i achieve to plurge the spaces in a string and at the end of the string i need to add ~ till 14 characters.

For example if my data in the text5 has `012 911 023 L`, then first i need to plurge as `012911023L`, then i need to  add ~ such that there are 14 characters in that text5 in total. So that output should be like `012911023L~~~~`
Please note this is not a C# or simple scripting like vb i found scripting is something is very different here in barteneder label vb scripting.

My code looks like below:

```
Dim sName
Dim fso
Dim fol

' get value from the text5
Set fol = Format.Objects("Text 1").Value

' go thru each files in the folder
For Each fil In fol.Files
    ' check if the file name contains tilde
    If InStr(1, fil.Name, "~") <> 0 Then
        ' replace tilde with space
        sName = Replace(fil.Name, "~", " ")
        ' rename the file
        fil.Name = sName
    End If
Next
```

For my above script I am getting an error called " `OnAutoSelectedEvent (Line 7):  Object required: '[string: "sample text"]'`

[Click here for my label text properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlnCk.jpg)

Comment: Doesn't look like `vbscript` - maybe `vb.net`?

Comment: The reason I was unsure is this line: `Set fol = Format.Objects("Text 1").Value` which appears to set fol to a folder somewhere (based on the `For Each` that comes directly after it, but in my experience, you would need to use a `Scripting.FileSystemObject` to create a reference to a folder that you could then use in this manner...

Comment: Yes, this is a vb.net, I am using that too

Comment: No i am not using the folder, I am using a text field character. May be my coding was wrong but can you re code if that is wrong

Comment: If `fol` is just a string that insert into a textfield, how do expect to extract to extract files from it? `For Each fil In fol.Files`

Comment: Hi I found the answer,

Comment: `Value = Format.Objects("Text 5").Value`

`Value = Replace(Value, " ", "")`

`Dim x `
`Dim Trim `
`x = Len(Value)`
`x = 14 - x`
`for d = 0 to x - 1`
`Value = Value &  "~"`
`next`

Comment: Can you tell me how can i take the above result and give to `Value = "#"+Call here the above result +Field("BarCodeData - Copy.BarCodeData - Copy.StarterType")`

Answer (score 1):

Below code will replace my string to above form

```
Value = Replace(Value, " ", "")

Dim length
Dim Trim
length= Len(Value)
length= 14 -length
for d = 0 to length - 1
Value = Value &  "~"
next
```